# How do I change the dimensions of a cylinder in PS CS6 for 3D mapping?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

Scenario : The standard cylinder for mapping in PS is a tall and skinny shape. I want to map to a "tuna can" shape. How do I edit the dimensions of the cylinder I want to map my 2D art to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the object and change the `Y` value in the `Coordinates` screen for the **Properties Panel**

[image]

[image]

You can also click-drag the `Y` arrow (the green one)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "uniform scaling" deselected also:

[image]